# How to print keys in string form?

Tags: python

something like

```
   d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

I want to print

```
 'a'
 'b'
 'c'
```

something like

```
 for (key, value) in d.items():

    print d[key]
```

will print out

```
 1
 2
 3
```

but how do you make keys in string form without using any other program such as itertools or stuff. It's simple python program.

AND I KNOW THAT d.keys() will print out list of keys

Comment: whats your question ? ... just `print "{0}".format(key)` doesnt work?...also d.keys is a list of keys it wont print it unless you say `print d.keys()`

Comment: Are you trying to get `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'` instead of `1`, `2`, `3`? Or something different?

Comment: Also, why are you doing `for (key, value) in d.items(): print d[key]` instead of just `for (key, value) in d.items(): print value`? The whole point of `items` is that you get both the key and value, and you've even stuck the value in a variable named `value`, so why look the value up with the key?

Comment: what's the point of doing d[key] then?? Sorry I am beginner in python but there is a question that uses mix of d[key] and value.

Comment: I think I know how to get '1', '2', '3' and 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 4):

Since you already know that `d.keys()` provides the list of keys, and you already know how `for` works with lists, why don't you just do:

```
for k in d.keys():
    print k
```

?

(or `repr(k)` if you want the string keys with their surrounding quotes)

Comment: for (key, value) in d.items():                                    print(key) this also worked

Comment: @EricJung: of course, but if you just need the `keys` why bother asking also for the values? :)